# New interpolated column from existing column and lookup table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to transform a column in a dataframe to get a new column, with each row in the new column interpolated from the old column and a lookup table. Example:

Original dataframe:

```
Date       StartingValue
2010-01-01            10
2010-01-02            25
2010-01-03            15
2010-01-04            20
```

Lookup Table dataframe:

```
StartingValue  NewValue
           10       500
           20      1200
           30      2750
```

Desired result:

```
Date       StartingValue  NewValue
2010-01-01            10       500
2010-01-02            25      1975
2010-01-03            15       850
2010-01-04            20      1200
```

The index will stay the same, and the interpolation should be linear between the closest rows in the lookup table.

I have looked at maybe `map()` or `apply()` but can't get a sense of how to use them here, especially with the interpolation. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[numpy.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) has this feature:

```
import numpy as np

df['NewValue'] = np.interp(df['StartingValue'].values,
                           lookup_table['StartingValue'].values,
                           lookup_table['NewValue'].values)
```

Comment: Slick - upvoted. One thing to note from the docs is that `lookup_table['StartingValue'].values` "must be increasing if argument `period` is not specified."

Comment: @Alex, good point. I noted this was true in lookup_table provided, but important to note that it is a requirement.

Comment: Awesome, that worked great. Much better than what I was trying. And good to know about the increasing requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The numpy option is more succinct, but here is how you can perform this task just with pandas:

```
vals = lookup['StartingValue']
df.merge(lookup.set_index('StartingValue').reindex( \
  range(vals.min(), vals.max()+1, 5)).interpolate().reset_index(), \
  on='StartingValue')
#          Date  StartingValue  NewValue
# 0  2010-01-01             10     500.0
# 1  2010-01-02             25    1975.0
# 2  2010-01-03             15     850.0
# 3  2010-01-04             20    1200.0
```